# do you have to have guest additions for enabling shared clipboard?

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I read somewhere online that if you select your oracle virtual machine and then press "settings", "advanced" and make the clipboard bidirectional you should be able to copy and paste from your host to the guest and vice versa, but it does not work, it simply ignores my copied text and it pastes the last thing that i have copied before.

After some reading i have stumbled over some tutorials that are using and downloading "guest additions", In no tutorial it was stated as mandatory and regularly it just mentioned as a useful extension that you can add to your virtual machine and adding shared clipboard described as just a bonus.

All of this is leading to my question, do you have to have guest additions for enabling shared clipboard? or should it work anyway?

Edit: just to be clear I'm using debian 10 as vm and windows 10 as host

[image]

Comment: I just installed guest additions and don't ask too many questions. If everyone was like me, we (humans) would still live in caves and eat berries.

Comment: Refer to the question please, I have not asked about installing it, I asked about the shared clipboard enabling, is it mandatory to have guest additions in order to enable clipboard sharing?

Comment: I know; if I knew the answer, I'd write it. I just *commented* ... unsuccessfully, though. Sorry.

Comment: That's ok, thank you very much for commenting anyway. On the subject matter, can you confirm it's working with guest additions?

Comment: I can confirm that - on my home laptop which runs Windows 7 as *host* and XP as *guest*, with bidirectional shared clipboard enabled, using VirtualBox 6.0.20, everything works OK. In other words, what I copy *here* gets pasted *there*, without any problems you described. Tried both directions (host-guest and vice versa). I can't confirm what happens with guest additions as I didn't install that at home (but did at work, and - I'm home now).

Comment: I'm using debian10 as vm and windows 10 as host, so that is helpful but not in my spacific case, but thank you though, it specifies the problem to my spacific vm.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. I hope you'll be able to fix it.